# Ошибка доступа к адресу

Tags: delphi, классы

Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
type Tq = class(Tobject)
    procedure l;
private
       type ImageInfo = record
       width : integer;
       height:integer;
       srcDC,bufDC: hdc;
end;
    var imgInf:imageinfo;
    function q(x,y:integer):integer;
 end;
```

Возникает ошибка при присвоении значения переменной imginf. Ошибка EAccsesViolation. Что делать?

**Добавлено.**

Код:

```
type TGagGraph = class(Tobject)
   type ImageInfo = record
       width : integer;
       height:integer;
        srcDC,bufDC: hdc;
  end;

   var imgInf:imageinfo;

  function GGinit(srcHDC: hwnd): pointer;
    procedure setPixel(x,y:integer; color:TRGBQuad; srcBMPbits: pointer);
    function getPixel(x,y:integer;  srcBMPbits: pointer): TRGBQuad;
    procedure repaint_dc;
      constructor Create;
private
    function XY_to_BMP_cell_number(x,y:integer):integer;
end;

function rgba(r,g,b,a:byte):TRGBQuad;

implementation
function rgba(r,g,b,a:byte):TRGBQuad;
    begin
      result.rgbBlue:=b;
      result.rgbGreen:=g;
      result.rgbRed:=r;
     result.rgbReserved:=a;
    end;

    constructor TGagGraph.Create;
    begin
     imginf.width:=0;           // <------- Exception class EAccsesViolation with messgae 'Accses violation at adress 00435eaf in module re.exe'.
    end;
```

Comment: Приведенный код скомпилился и адекватно отработал. Попробуйте отрезать все лишнее. Или пересобрать начисто. Может линковщик напортачил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы обьект класса создали?
Если да, то попробуйте сделать данную переменную публичной:

```
> type Tq = class(Tobject)
>     procedure l; private
>        type ImageInfo = record
>        width : integer;
>        height:integer;
>        srcDC,bufDC: hdc; public   // кстати, здесь был подозрительный
> "end;"
>     var imgInf:imageinfo;
>     function q(x,y:integer):integer;  end;
```

Comment: я работаю с переменной из процедуры объекта этого класса.
т.е.:

    var tobj: Tq;
    begin
       tobj.l;
    end; 

   //---------------------------вот процедура l
  procedure l;
  begin
     imgInfo.width:=199;
  end;

Как мне быть?

Comment: Ошибка появляется в run-time программы: ошибка доступа к адресу.  Я так понимаю под переменную не выделяется памяти.

Comment: Надеюсь, у вас есть реализация метода "l()".

Попробуйте переместить определение метода в одну секцию с "imginfo" и уберите "var" перед "imginfo" .

Comment: Все попробовал, не получается. Вопрос обновлен.